# how to get website link from javascript:void(0) with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrap venue website link from this website:
https://www.venuereport.com/venue/al-maha-a-luxury-collection-desert-resort-spa/

The element for this part is:

```
<div class="vr_widget_text" style="padding-top: 2px"><img src="https://www.venuereport.com/build/static/shape@3x.png" class="ShapeLast"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="coolmustard-btn">Website</a></div>
```

How can get website link from this element?

Comment: To clarify your question, please state what should be the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If all the pages are similar to the one you have given the link, here is the snippet to extract the website link:

```js
  const websitePopup = document.getElementById('outbound-interstitial');
  const href = websitePopup.querySelector('a');
  const link = href.getAttribute('href');
  console.log('Venue Webiste Link:', link);
```

[image: ✨]

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are unable to access the hotel website directly. Instead, a pop-up window appears, which displays a button saying 'That's okay, take me to the website'. So, by clicking on this button, you can access the URL of the hotel.
So what you have to do is, click on WebSite button:

```
web_site_button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Website")
web_site_button.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='That's okay, take me to the website ']"))
            
take_me_to_website_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text()="That's okay, take me to the website "])
web_site_url = take_me_to_website_button.get_attribute("href")
```

**Note: I cannot see any iFrame within Dom, it can be that problem and also you have to use waits accordingly. I just tried to provide you with solution.**